# How to use grep command to search for multiple patterns in perl?

Tags: perl

How to use grep command to search for multiple fields in perl?

I have below file

File1:

```
access abc permit tcp sourceipaddress sourcesubnet destipaddr destsubnet eq portnumber
```

Here I'm splitting based on fields and grepping for those fields in an array but it does not seem to work (Tried 4 different ways which are commented below but nothing worked)

```
 my @columns = split(' ',$line);
    my $fld0 = $columns[3];
    my $fld3 = $columns[6];
    my $fld5 = $columns[9];

    #my @gitLines = grep "$fld0" && $_ =~ "$sIP" && $_ =~ "$dIP" && $_ =~ "$fld5"} @gitFile;

  #my @gitLines = @gitFile =~ /$fld0|$sIP|$dIP|$fld5/;

#my @gitLines = grep /$fld0/ && /$sIP/ && /$dIP/ && /$fld5/, @gitFile;

#grep {$fld0} && {$sIP} && {$dIP} && {$fld5} @gitFile;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl's `grep` takes a block of code<sup>(*)</sup> and gives the array elements as `$_` to the block. `/pattern/` matches implicitly against `$_` and we can combine the pattern matches with `&&` or `||`. So these should work:

```
my @foo = qw/abc cde efg ghi/;
printf("%s\n", join(" ",  grep {/c/ || /e/} @foo));
printf("%s\n", join(" ",  grep {/c/ && /e/} @foo));
```

The first one prints the elements of `@foo` that have either `c` or `e`, the second prints the one that has both.

<sub>(* or an expression, but I find the block syntax more clear)</sub>

---

```
#my @gitLines = grep "$fld0" && $_ =~ "$sIP" && $_ =~ "$dIP" && $_ =~ "$fld5"} @gitFile;
```

You're missing the opening brace here, and `"$fld0"` by itself doesn't test anything but the contents of `$fld0`.

```
#my @gitLines = grep /$fld0/ && /$sIP/ && /$dIP/ && /$fld5/, @gitFile;
```

I think this should actually work, it's the same as my second line, except with an expression and not a block. But perhaps you wanted `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: What kind of construct are the comma separated commands?

Comment: I mean this: `printf "%s\n", join " ",  grep {/c/ || /e/} @foo;`.

Comment: @tomas, it's just function calls without the parenthesis. It's a bit ugly in that it only works as long as you don't need to give `printf` any arguments after whatever `join` returns, since without the parenthesis there's no way to tell if additional arguments should go to `join` or `printf`.

Comment: my @gitLines = printf("%s\n", join(" ", grep {/$fld0/ && /sIP/ && /dIP/ && /$fld5/} @gitLines_mst)); did not work. It is giving me output as 1 where in I want the entire line extracted if those fields match.

Comment: @Vibes, um, yes. Since that's what [`printf` returns](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html). But you don't want to print anything, so you don't need the `printf` part. Just take the parts you do need.